# bundle command prompts for github login which doesn't work

Tags: ruby, git, github, rubygems, bundler

When I run bundle I get this:

```
$ bundle
Following files may not be writable, so sudo is needed:
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/build_info
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/cache
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/doc
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/extensions
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/specifications
Fetching https://github.com/lsegal/yard.git
Fetching https://github.com/lsegal/yard-js.git
Fetching https://github.com/lsegal/parsejs.git
Username for 'https://github.com': me
Password for 'https://me@github.com': 
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/lsegal/parsejs.git/'

Retrying `git clone 'https://github.com/lsegal/parsejs.git' "/Users/me/.bundle/cache/git/parsejs-35f0b5a29373e174672dd4f95a4392093a2ddf51" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet` due to error (2/4): Bundler::Source::Git::GitCommandError Git error: command `git clone 'https://github.com/lsegal/parsejs.git' "/Users/me/.bundle/cache/git/parsejs-35f0b5a29373e174672dd4f95a4392093a2ddf51" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet` in directory /Users/paulcarron/git/ibm-cos-sdk-js has failed.
Username for 'https://github.com': me
Password for 'https://me@github.com': 
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/lsegal/parsejs.git/' not found

Retrying `git clone 'https://github.com/lsegal/parsejs.git' "/Users/me/.bundle/cache/git/parsejs-35f0b5a29373e174672dd4f95a4392093a2ddf51" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet` due to error (3/4): Bundler::Source::Git::GitCommandError Git error: command `git clone 'https://github.com/lsegal/parsejs.git' "/Users/me/.bundle/cache/git/parsejs-35f0b5a29373e174672dd4f95a4392093a2ddf51" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet` in directory /Users/paulcarron/git/ibm-cos-sdk-js has failed.
Username for 'https://github.com':
```

I logged in to GitHub through the browser with the same username so don't know what's going on. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Github Token to access via the command line API. Go to [`Settings -> Developer Settings -> Access Tokens`](https://github.com/settings/tokens) and create a new token.

I'm not entirely certain which set you need. I gave myself `repo` (all), `write:packages`, `read:packages`, and `workflow` because that's what I wanted on that token. My guess is that `read:packages` will be sufficient.

You can then provide your normal Github username and this new token when bundle prompts for it.